# Can I write custom assertions in CxxTest?

Tags: assertions, cxxtest

I'm just starting to use CxxTest and would like to test whether a std::vector has been sorted correctly. Here's my test so far:

```
void testSort() {
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // This could be any sorting function

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i) {
    TS_ASSERT(vec[i] <= vec[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

Obviously, CxxTest does not provide a `TS_ASSERT_SORTED` assertion, but is there a way to write custom assertions? That would allow me to do this:

```
void testSort() {
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // This could be any sorting function

  TS_ASSERT_SORTED(vec);
}
```

It's significantly easier to see the intent of the test when it's written this way.

I looked through the CxxTest [user's guide](http://cxxtest.sourceforge.net/guide.html) but couldn't figure out whether you can write custom assertions like this. As an alternative, I could write a class IsSorted and implement its `operator()`. I could then write the test like this:

```
void testSort() {
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // This could be any sorting function

  TS_ASSERT_PREDICATE(IsSorted, vec);
}
```

I'm guessing this is the correct approach. If I do this, though, should I place the definition of `class IsSorted` in its own header file, separate from my test suite? I'm still trying to figure out the best practices associated with unit testing, especially in this framework.

One final question: should I be sorting the vector in the `setUp()` method or in the test itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a few new macros of your own by changing cxxtest header files. It's open source, after-all! Make sure you fail the test correctly from those macros (see what TS_ASSERT_EQUALS do, unlike the example given here by martiert which is not compatible with how cxxtest work).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the assertions are just preprocessor macros, so you could probably implement them however you want, and then #define a macro for them. I'd think it'd be better to use a name that doesn't start with `TS_ASSERT_`, so that you don't confuse later readers of the code.

The predicate version doesn't look all that clumsy to me - I'd probably go with that, or possibly implement a check_ method on the class you're testing, and call that from the test. I often end up needing methods that validate the internal structure of the class for run-time debugging & logging, anyway...

Answer (score -1):

You could use a #define

```
#define TS_ASSERT_PREDICATE( vec )\
    std::vector tmp = vec;\
    for(int i = 0; i  tmp[i+1]) \
            return false;\ 
    }\ 
    return true;\ 
}
```

Comment: The `TS_ASSERT` macros must do more than return a bool...otherwise, how would the variable values be output when a test failed?